# Proving this theorem without using Induction

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, alternative-proof

In my linear algebra class, my teacher stated the following theorem:

> Let $E$ be a vector space over a field $K$ and let $S_1=\{u_1,...,u_p\}$ and $S_2=\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ subsets of $E$ such that $S_1$ is linearly independent and $S_1\subseteq L(S_2)$, where $L(S_2)$ is the set of all linear combinations of $S_2$. Then:
>
> - $p\leq n$
> - We can add to $S_1$ $n-p$ vectors of $S_2$ such that the resulting set generates $L(S_2)$

I was trying to prove this myself but I wasn't able to. My teacher used Mathematical Induction to do so. Is there a way to do this more directly?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want to avoid mathematical induction? Mathematical induction is the tool of choice if you need to prove anything about "all natural numbers".

Comment: I was trying to prove it without using mathematical induction, and I was just curious to see if it's possible @LeeMosher

Comment: And I also didn't understand why using induction here. If we use induction on $p$ this isn't valid for all natural numbers, just $p\leq n$ @LeeMosher

Comment: Do induction on $n$ instead of on $p$.

Comment: Lee Mosher is right of course, but i'd like to point out that induction works fine for finite sets of numbers. The logic holds as long as the inductive step is true. For a finite set, the inductive step ceases to be true at exactly the point you don't need it anymore, because you have the result for every element of the set.